# Configure second wifi router on same LAN as primary?

Tags: router, lan, wireless-access-point, bridge

I bought a second home wifi router to extend my wireless coverage. It has a wired connection to the primary router and is configured with a different SSID. I'd also like the second router to perform more like a switch, fully exposing all connected devices to the others on the primary router's network.

I can't configure the second router as a wireless repeater, the two routers are different brands, and I don't want to install third-party firmware.

How can I configure the routers to make devices behave as if they are on the same local network?

Comment: What is the model name of the second router?

Comment: It's a TP Link WR841N, but brand/model shouldn't really matter much.  See below ansewer.

Answer (score 0):

To get the new router on the same LAN, follow these steps:

1. Make sure you connect the secondary router to the primary router using one of the secondary router's LAN ports, not its WAN port.
2. Then disable DHCP on the secondary router.
3. Configure your primary router to give your secondary router's IP address statically.
4. Finally, configure the secondary router with the static router IP address you just chose.

See [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/104469/how-to-extend-your-wi-fi-network-with-simple-access-points/) and [here](http://www.tp-link.com/en/FAQ-417.html) for more information.